# How to claim an automatic facebook page (That I have the rights for)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have the rights for a certain video game brand (won't disclose it here).
I searched facebook and found an automatic page for this brand, that was generated off Wikipedia, and has around 4,800 likes.

I would like to claim ownership of this page, and post my updates to fans, since I'm the legit owner of the brand.

I tried the instructions that are found here: https://www.facebook.com/help/257661877677443/, however they seem to be dated. There is no option such as "Is this your business?", or I couldn't find it anywhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try reporting the page?

Comment: @Sathya The "report" option only gives me items such as "violence", "spam" and so on. Nothing that addresses my need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot claim a topic. Any auto generated information from Wikipedia is a topic. If the page was auto generated by other means then yes you can claim it.

You can just set the Official Page to yours.

[image: Official Edit]

Comment: In facebook, it's categorised as "interest". It sounds strange to me, since I've "liked" certain rock band "interest" pages in the past, and I started getting postings from them - meaning they've claimed the pages somehow.
Is there a source that validates what you say? Thanks

Comment: @SirKnigget there isn't a source, I'm just using a little logic as all Wikipedia pages are not owned by any particular person, it will be a little weird for Facebook to transfer control unless it's a major source of confusion.